# Сортировка строк, содержащие цифры и точки

Tags: java, строки, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать правильно массив строк:

```
String[] strings = {"2.4.2", "2.4.20", "2.4.20.1", "2.4.20.1.1", "2.4.2.1", "2.4.21", "2.4.2.10", "2.4.2.100", "2.4.2.100.1", "2.4.2.100.102", "2.4.2.11.102", "2.4.2.2.1", "2.4.3", "2.4.2.10.1"};
```

Подскажите как правильно это сделать на Java?

Должно получиться так:

> 2.4.2
>   2.4.2.1
>   2.4.2.2.1
>   2.4.2.10
>   2.4.2.10.1
>   2.4.2.11.102
>   2.4.2.100
>   2.4.2.100.1
>   2.4.2.100.102
>   2.4.3
>   2.4.20
>   2.4.20.1
>   2.4.20.1.1
>   2.4.21

Comment: Почему `2.4.2 < 2.4.2.1` но `2.4.2.10 > 2.4.2.10.1`?

Comment: Спасибо за указание ошибки, поправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно разбить строки на отдельные числа и сравнить полученные массивы, после чего собрать строки обратно. В Java 9 имеется специальный метод `Arrays.compare(int[] a, int[] b)` для сравнения массивов целых чисел, а если используется версия Java ниже - нужно будет самим написать метод сравнения (а можно просто скопировать реализацию из Java 9) как-то так:

```java
int mismatchArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    int mismatch = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            mismatch = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return mismatch;
}

int compareArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int i = mismatchArrays(a, b);
    if (i >= 0 && i < Math.min(a.length, b.length)) {
        return Integer.compare(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
}
```

После этого уже можно написать основную часть:

```java
String[] strings = {"2.4.2", "2.4.20", "2.4.20.1", "2.4.20.1.1", "2.4.2.1", "2.4.21", "2.4.2.10", "2.4.2.100", "2.4.2.100.1", "2.4.2.100.102", "2.4.2.11.102", "2.4.2.2.1", "2.4.3", "2.4.2.10.1"};

Stream.of(strings)
    .map(str -> Stream.of(str.split("\\."))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray()
    )
    .sorted(Test::compareArrays)
    .map(ints -> IntStream.of(ints)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("."))
    )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Интересный метод. Спасибо. Буду пробовать